# How can I find out the failed login attempts in windows cygwin open ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, openssh

How can I find out the failed login attempts in windows cygwin open ssh
i looked inside this path but did not find any logs with failed attempts

`C:\cygwin\var\log`

Comment: Are you referring to sshd logging? See http://techtorials.me/cygwin/logging/

Comment: yes, sshd loggin. trying to see all the failed attempts.

Comment: The link in my comment above tells you how to configure logging ...

Comment: @DavidPostill SSHD logs and auth logs are different.